# C# create an association between nodes

Tags: c#

I have a library class that has a `Serve()` method. What it does is dequeue a person from a queue and Pop a book from a stack. A `Book` is associated to a `Borrower` when it is borrowed, that way the method `ReturnBook()` can accept a string value that corresponds to the name of the person who borrowed the book.

How can I create an association between the Book and the Borrower? It's my first time encountering associations in C#. Here is a sample input and output

```
INPUT
Lineup("Joker")
Add("Shelter", "Yung Jun", "9781250075611")
Add("The Paper Menagerie and Other Stories", "Liu, Ken", "9781481442541")
Serve()

Joker lined up.
Added Shelter (Yung Jun) to the stack.
Added The Paper Menagerie and Other Stories (Liu, Ken) to the stack.
Joker borrowed Shelter (Yung Jun)
```

Comment: Showing sample data and expected output may be helpful, but first we need to see the code and a problem description.

Comment: Generally any data record would have some sort of identifier, something which makes that record unique among other instances of that object.  When another object needs to be "associated" to that object, it would generally have some property on it which has a meaningful semantic name which carries the value of that other object's identifier.  So if the identifier of a Class A is an integer, and Class B needs to be associated with an instance of it, then Class B might have some integer property which would carry the identifier of the associated instance of Class A.

Comment: To start with, however, you should create classes for your `Borrower` and `Book` objects.

Comment: Well this one of the hardest problems in programing. You might want to look at what a [Domain Model](http://csis.pace.edu/~marchese/CS389/L8/DomainModel-UML_short.pdf) is and then use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) to crate the [relationships](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn385704.aspx).

Comment: Your output is misleading. It says that a `Shelter ` was added to the `Stack`, followed by `Paper Menagerie`. However, the first book to be borrowed is `Shelter`. This implies that a `Queue` is being used to store the books, not a `Stack`, since stacks are FILO (first in last out) and queues are FIFO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a property of one item that is of the type of the other item. For example, a `Borrower` may have a `Book` property. Then, when the borrower borrows a book, you just set the value of the `Book` property to the book they just borrowed.

Following is an illustrative example of how this might work:

To start with, you should create some classes to represent the objects. Here's an example:

```
class Reader
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Book BorrowedBook { get; set; }
}

class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
}
```

And it looks like you have a `Queue` of `Readers` (called `borrowers`) and a `Stack` of `Books`. I also created a `Queue` of `Readers` called `returners`, which will represent the people who want to return a book:

```
class Program
{
    private static Queue<Reader> borrowers = new Queue<Reader>();
    private static Queue<Reader> returners = new Queue<Reader>();
    private static Stack<Book> books = new Stack<Book>();
```

Now, it looks like you have some helper methods that will add a reader to the queue or a book to the stack. Since I can see that these may need to be used to add new items OR existing items (like when a reader returns a book, the existing book will get added back to the library), I create two versions of them - one with no arguments (which will then get the details of the object from the user), and one with an argument (which will add that object to the queue or stack):

```
private static void Lineup()
{
    var newReader = new Reader();
    Console.Write("Enter the name of the new reader: ");
    newReader.Name = Console.ReadLine();

    // Now that we have a reader object, call the 
    // other version of this method to add it
    Lineup(newReader);
}

private static void Lineup(Reader borrower)
{
    borrowers.Enqueue(borrower);
    Console.WriteLine($"{borrower.Name} lined up to borrow a book.");
}

private static void Add()
{
    var newBook = new Book();
    Console.Write("Enter the book title: ");
    newBook.Title = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter the book author: ");
    newBook.Author = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter the book ISBN: ");
    newBook.ISBN = Console.ReadLine();

    // Now that we have a book object, call the 
    // other version of this method to add it
    Add(newBook);
}

private static void Add(Book book)
{
    books.Push(book);
    Console.WriteLine($"Added '{book.Title}' to the library.");
}
```

Finally, we need some methods to service our borrowers (`Dequeue` a borrower and `Pop` a book, then give the book to the borrower) and our returners (`Push` the book back to the library, and, if the person wants to borrow another one, `Enqueue` them back in the borrowers line):

```
private static void ServiceBorrower()
{
    if (borrowers.Count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There are no more borrowers waiting in line.");
    }
    else if (books.Count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There are no more books to loan.");
        if (returners.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" - Hint: There are people waiting to return books.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var borrower = borrowers.Dequeue();
        var book = books.Pop();

        borrower.BorrowedBook = book;
        Console.WriteLine($"{borrower.Name} borrowed {book.Title}");
        returners.Enqueue(borrower);
    }
}

private static void ServiceReturner()
{
    if (returners.Count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There are no more returners waiting in line.");
    }
    else
    {
        var returner = returners.Dequeue();
        var book = returner.BorrowedBook;
        returner.BorrowedBook = null;

        Add(book);
        Console.WriteLine($"{returner.Name} has returned {book.Title}.");
        Console.Write("Do they want to borrow another one (Y/N)?: ");
        var input = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();

        if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
        {
            Lineup(returner);
        }                
    }
}
```

Now, we just need to give our user some options as to what they want the program to do, and continue looping on their input until they decide to quit:

```
static void Main()
{
    bool exit = false;

    Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option:");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Enter a new reader");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Enter a new book");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Service the next borrower");
    Console.WriteLine("4. Service the next returner");
    Console.WriteLine("5. Exit the program");

    while (!exit)
    {
        Console.Write("\nEnter choice (1-5): ");

        int input;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) || input < 1 || input > 5)
        {
            Console.Write("Invalid input. Enter a number from 1-5: ");
        }

        switch(input)
        {
            case 1:
                Lineup();
                break;
            case 2:
                Add();
                break;
            case 3:
                ServiceBorrower();
                break;
            case 4:
                ServiceReturner();
                break;
            case 5:
                exit = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

[image]